# How can I insert an entire input stream (up to EOF) into an output stream?

Tags: external-files, expl3, auxiliary-files

I am trying to automate the generation of a text version of my resume.
I'd like to incorporate a note to any potential human readers (most plain text resumes are, to my understanding, simply scanned by data mining programs).
However, doing this within `expl3` itself is tedious—there's only so many times you can see `\c_space_tl` before it loses its individuality and personal character.

I'd like to simple set up a means to grab the entire contents of an external file by path and shove it into the stream I'm writing.
What is the most straightforward way to do this?

I've a setup that looks like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_const:Nn \g_resume_preamble_path_tl { preamble.txt }
\tl_const:Nn \g_resume_textout_path_tl { resume.out.txt }

\ior_new:N \g_resume_preamble_ior
\ior_open:Nn \g_resume_preamble_ior { \g_resume_preamble_path_tl }
\iow_new:N \g_resume_textout_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_resume_textout_iow { \g_resume_textout_path_tl }

\begin{document}
ducks
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `cp preamble.txt resume.out.txt` simpler?

Comment: @egreg Sure it would be, but (as far as I'm aware) `iow` overwrites the file at the destination at every run. I would be doing this manually every time I compile for submission.

Comment: Tell arara to do it!

Comment: @egreg but but but but build tools *frighten* me :( I'll look into it as an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is read a file line by line and 'do stuff' with the input, then the (experimental) `\ior_str_map_inline:Nn` seems to be what you are after:

```
\ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_resume_preamble_ior
  { \iow_now:Nn \g_resume_textout_iow {#1} }
```

(We don't have a 'catchfile` equivalent pre-built, although clearly you can manage more-or-less that idea with a mapping.)

Comment: I've used a string mapping as the way the question is phrased suggests a verbatim copy: I assume in the real case there is a bit more to this.

Comment: Actually there isn't—a verbatim copy is all that's required :)

Comment: @SeanAllred In that case I'd go with egreg's solution!

Comment: This solution works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 7):

[image: woohoo]

egreg suggested the use of `arara`, so I'll provide a rule to, well, copy a file. `:)` I might include some file handling rules in the next version in order to ease these tasks.

Without further ado, here's the rule, named `copy.yaml`:

```
!config
identifier: copy
name: Copy
command: <arara> @{isTrue(isNotEmpty(source) && isNotEmpty(target), copy.concat(' "').concat(source).concat('" "').concat(target).concat('"'))}
arguments:
- identifier: copy
  default: <arara> @{isWindows('cmd /c copy', 'cp')}
- identifier: source
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.source}
- identifier: target
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.target}
```

The idea behind this rule is to copy `source` to `target` or  do nothing when either of the two is missing. The `isWindows` function helps us to prevent unknown commands when switching from one OS to another. A sample usage is, in your `.tex` file:

```
% arara: copy: { source: preamble.txt, target: resume.out.txt }
% arara: pdflatex
% ...
\documentclass{article}
...
```

And we are done. `:)`

Comment: I appreciate the warning. That was close. *Perhaps this is a good time to finally try `arara` after all…*

Comment: @Sean: don't worry, I can name some friends that use `arara` way more than I do. `:)`

Comment: @SeanAllred you won't regret it! I can't image the TeXworld before `arara` any more (http://www.mychemistry.eu/tag/arara/)